# Passenger Module Fails On AWS Gem With 'Class Variable Name' Error

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Opening Disclaimer: I'm all kinds of newb to the technologies involved in this question. But the Googles, she no yield-a the fruit.

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app into production. This app works fine using WEBRick. I am also using the AWS gem to retrieve data from S3.

I have installed and set up Nginx with Passenger. When I hit the page I'm testing I get this error:

```
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: `@@{' is not allowed as a class variable name
/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
    unless defined? @@{:instance_writer=>false}
                      ^ (SyntaxError)
```

I guess something about Nginx/Passenger/Who-Knows is choking on the AWS code, but again, using WEBRick, I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the fact that `aws-s3` is doing something evil.  If you look at the code in that stack trace, you can see that they open class `Class` and add cattr_reader and cattr_writer. ActiveSupport also does this and adds methods by those same names to `Module` I do not have the code but I am pretty sure that when you use Passenger, it is including the ActiveSupport 4.0 version of `cattr_reader`/`cattr_writer` and blowing up on this.

My solution would to be to replace `aws-s3` with the newer and more functional `aws-sdk`

Comment: I tried the aws-sdk library but it looked like they had removed the ability to get a temporarily signed URL for an s5 resource. If not, then they moved it into a different class. I could not find it. I wound up rewriting the logic in the front end, using the aws library for js, and using node.js for some light back end stuff. Everything works fine, and I found it much easier to deal with.